# Is it safe to call a non-virtual base class member function from the base class destructor using a derived class pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14, derived-class, base-class

This is my general question: *Is it safe to call a non-virtual base class member function from the base class destructor using a derived class pointer that is getting destroyed*?

Let me explain this by the following example.

I have a *Base* class and a derived *Key* class.

```
static unsigned int count = 0;                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                              
class Base;                                                                                                                                                   
class Key;                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                              
void notify(const Base *b);                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                              
class Base                                                                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                                             
public:                                                                                                                                                       
  Base(): id(count++) {}                                                                                                                                      
  virtual ~Base() { notify(this); }                                                                                                                           
  int getId() const { return id; }                                                                                                                            
  virtual int dummy() const = 0;                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                              
private:                                                                                                                                                      
  unsigned int id;                                                                                                                                            
};                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                              
class Key : public Base                                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                             
public:                                                                                                                                                       
  Key() : Base() {}                                                                                                                                           
  ~Key() {}                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                              
  int dummy() const override { return 0; }                                                                                                                    
};
```

I now create an *std::map* (*std::set* will also work) of derived *Key* class pointers sorted by their *id* as follows:

```
struct Comparator1                                                                                                                                            
{                                                                                                                                                             
  bool operator()(const Key *k1, const Key *k2) const                                                                                                         
  {                                                                                                                                                           
    return k1->getId() < k2->getId();                                                                                                                         
  }                                                                                                                                                           
};

std::map<const Key*, int, Comparator1> myMap;
```

Now as and when a *Key* gets deleted, I want to erase that key from myMap. To do this I first tried implementing the *notify* method triggered from *~Base()* as follows, but I know this is not safe and can result in an undefined-behavior. I have verified this here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e6cd86a9706afa1

```
void notify(const Base* b)
{
    myMap.erase(static_cast<const Key *>(b)); //not safe, results in UB
}
```

So to circumvent this issue, I defined a heterogenous Comparator and used variant (4) of [std::map::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) to find the key in the map and then passed that iterator to erase as follows:

```
struct Comparator2                                                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                             
  using is_transparent = std::true_type;                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                              
  bool operator()(const Key *k1, const Key *k2) const                                                                                                  
  {                                                                                                                                                           
    return k1->getId() < k2->getId();                                                                                                                         
  }                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                              
  bool operator()(const Key *k1, const Base *b1) const                                                                                                 
  {                                                                                                                                                           
    return k1->getId() < b1->getId();                                                                                                                         
  }                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                              
  bool operator()(const Base *b1, const Key *k1) const                                                                                                 
  {                                                                                                                                                           
    return b1->getId() < k1->getId();                                                                                                                         
  }                                                                                                                                                           
};      
                                                                                                                                                              
std::map<const Key*, int, Comparator2> myMap; 

void notify(const Base* b)
{
    // myMap.erase(static_cast<const Key *>(b)); //not safe, results in UB
    
    auto it = myMap.find(b);                                                                                                                                    
    if (it != myMap.end())                                                                                                                                      
        myMap.erase(it);
}
```

I have tested this second version with g++ and clang and I am not seeing any undefined behavior. You can try the code here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65f6e7498bdf06f7

So is my second version using *Comparator2* and *std::map::find* safe? As inside the *Comparator2*, I am still using a pointer to the derived *Key* class whose destructor has already been called. I do not see any error using g++ or clang compiler, so could you please advise if this code is safe?

Thanks,

Varun

---

Edit: I just realized that *Comparator2* can be further simplified by directly using the *Base* class pointer as follows:

```
struct Comparator2                                                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                             
  using is_transparent = std::true_type;                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                              
  bool operator()(const Base *k1, const Base *k2) const                                                                                                  
  {                                                                                                                                                           
    return k1->getId() < k2->getId();                                                                                                                         
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
};
```

This also works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7c10c115c20f5b6

Comment: Kind of related, but this entire architecture seems very sketchy and fragile. Why do you need to handle this in a destructor call? IMO it would be better to abstract the usage of `Key` away from the user behind some manager class (that would be the only one allowed to create and delete the instances), maybe in combination with some form of smart pointer

Comment: This seems overly complicated. What's the intended use-case?

Comment: I am working on a huge code base that relies on this kind of a framework. There are hundreds of Classes derived from one single _Base_ class, and we have maps and sets used in thousands of places within the code that use _Derived_ class pointers as keys. At most places we have some manager or observer that is responsible for cleaning these maps/sets but it is not done consistently. I was hoping to come up with a more general wrapper over the existing maps/sets that automatically cleans itself using the notification triggered from the _Base_ class destructor.

Comment: @VarunHiremath I don't think your use-case changes the result, this is not a nice solution, but if you take the view the risk vs time refactoring is worth it then its up to you. You *can* delete an object from within the object member function calls - but you need to be very careful. If you are going to use this type of approach (especially since your project sounds large / multi-person) you are going to need to make it very clear to any other developers to be very careful editing code in this area such that a member function/variable/etc. is *not* accessed once this notification is called...

Comment: Hi @code_fodder, thanks for your response! While I understand that the notification sent from the Base class dtor with this pointer is not safe to use. For instance in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861245/passing-the-this-pointer-to-other-class-function-in-destructor) it is clearly explained that calling a _virtual function_, _typeid_, _dynamic_cast_, etc  is not safe. But in this particular case I am just using a non-virtual method from the Base class. So I was wondering if this is 100% safe (according to C++ standard) or can this also result in some UB during runtime?

Comment: @VarunHiremath I'll add an update to my answer below...

Answer (score 1):

Unless I have mis-understood your code, then this is basically the same as an object that has a function that destroys itself (e.g. `delete this;)` - which is legal - provided that you do nothing after the deletion that relies on your object existing - like calling member functions or accessing member variables etc...

So looking at your code, I think you are ok - your pointer to the object is now UB if you use it again obviously, and the returning back up the stack of function calls looks safe.

But I would strongly suggest another approach - this will most Likely be a maintenance nightmare - if an unsuspecting developer later changes this code they very well may cause UB.

UnholySheep's idea of a separate class that manages all this for you sound much better :)

**update**

all you are really doing here is calling a normal function (`notify()`) which in turn calls the member (non virtual) `getId()` function via the comparator function via map.erase/find. This all occurs inside the destructor functions scope - which is fine. Here is a rough call trace of what happens when you call delete:

```
~Base()
    |
    v
  notify()
      |
      v
    Comparator() // This happens a number of times
        |
        v
      getId()    // This is called by Comparator
        |
   +----+           
   |
   v
~Base()          // base destructor returns
```

So you can see all the member (`getId()`) calls are done within the Base class d'tor function - and this is safe.

What I might suggest so that you don't have to write your "heterogenous Comparator" (Comparitor2), and to make your design/work easier, is make your map use the base class pointer: `std::map<const Base*, int, Comparator1> myMap;` then you can get rid of your Comparitor2 struct and you can use `map.erase(b)` directly in your `notify()` function and all this becomes a lot cleaner/clearer.  Here is an example with some annotations (prints): https://godbolt.org/z/h5zTc9

Comment: Hi @code_fodder, thanks for the explanation. I agree that if I build the map using _Base_ class pointer, then no doubt everything is good. But we need the map to be built using _Key_ pointer, as we use both the _Key_ and _Value_. So the _ambiguity_ really originates from the usage of _Key_ class pointer in the map. You will notice the call stack is exactly the same if you use my modified _Comparator2_ with _find_ & _erase_ methods. The only question is since _~Key()_ has already finished by the time we reach _~Base()_, so is dereferencing _Key_ pointer and invoking _getId()_ still valid?

Comment: yes this is safe :)  - often there is some work to do in the base class (like closing down "stuff") that can even be hidden away from the derived. I didn't quite understand your point about having to access the `Key` - you can still do this if your map is a map of `base` - but you will then need to static (or if unknown, dynamic) cast - so this could end up being less nice - depending on your code - so that is your call :)